# Heroku: POST Error 414 (Request-URI Too Long)

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, heroku

**DESIRED BEHAVIOUR:**

The Post request works and the poll is saved in the database.

---

**SITUATION:**

My SPA works fine on my local machine. But when uploaded to Heroku, it gives me a 414 error when I try to create a Poll.

What is causing this and how do I fix it ?

---

Here is the `POST` code for the creation of a poll. It passes the user token through the request header so I can retrieve it on the backend to authorise the creation of the poll. The only issue I have now is that I get an error 400 :/

---

**CODE:**

**client**

```
addPoll(poll: Poll) {
    const body = JSON.stringify(poll);
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
        ? '?token=' + localStorage.getItem('token')
        : '';
    const options = new RequestOptions();
    if (!options.headers) {
        options.headers = new Headers({
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token
        });
    }
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/poll', body,  options)
        .map((response: Response) => {
            const result = response.json();
            const poll = new Poll(
                result.obj.title,
                result.obj.choice1,
                result.obj.choice2,
                0,
                0,
                result.obj.user.firstName,
                result.obj._id,
                result.obj.user._id,
                );
            this.polls.unshift(poll);
            return poll;
        })
        .catch((error: Response) => {
            this.errorService.handleError(error.json());
            return Observable.throw(error);
        });
}
```

**server**

```
function getToken (req) {
    if (req.options.headers.authorization && req.options.headers.authorization.split(' ')[0] === 'Bearer') {
        console.log("WE ARE IN!");
        return req.options.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    }
    return null;
  }

router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("token: "+getToken(req));
    var decoded = jwt.decode(getToken(req));
    User.findById(decoded.user._id, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                title: 'An error occurred',
                error: err
            });
        }
        var poll = new Poll({
            title: req.body.title,
            choice1: req.body.choice1,
            choice2: req.body.choice2,
            counter1: 0,
            counter2: 0,
            user: user
        });

        poll.save(function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    title: 'An error occurred',
                    error: err
                });
            }
            user.polls.push(result);
            user.save();
            res.status(201).json({
                poll: 'Saved poll',
                obj: result
            });
        });
    });
});
```

---

**ERROR:**

[image]

Comment: 414 means that your URL is too long, can't you use a header for your token ?

Comment: @trichetriche How would that work ?

Comment: It's the JWT auth, you put your token in a `Authorization` header, that contains `Bearer [yourTokenHere]`

Comment: @Coder1000, are you still getting error?

Comment: @Sravan I am :/ Error 400

Comment: @Coder1000, at what point you are getting the error?

Comment: @Sravan I fill the three fields and click save to create the poll. The poll is not saved and I get the error you can see in the screeshot I put in the question

Comment: @Coder1000, you are sending wrong token, currently the token is being sent as,`Authorization:Bearer ?token= your-token,` but you should send as, `Authorization:Bearer your-token,`

Comment: @Sravan EXACTLY ! Finally :D THX !

Comment: @Sravan Please add your answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: @Coder1000, okay adding answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked your code and tested the `network calls`, you have **two issues**.

**1) while signing up, you didnot allow `lastName` to go to server, so unable to `signUp`**

So, the parameters should be,

```
{
    "email": "test@mailinator.com",
    "firstName": "test",
    "lastName": "test",
    "password": "12345678",
    "votes": "test"
}
```

**2) Token, should be passed through headers instead of query parameter.**

You have error in,

**`const token = localStorage.getItem('token') ? '?token=' + localStorage.getItem('token') : '';`**

Should be

**`const token = localStorage.getItem('token') ? localStorage.getItem('token') : '';`**

```
addPoll(poll: Poll) {
    const body = JSON.stringify(poll);
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
        ? localStorage.getItem('token')
        : '';
    const options = new RequestOptions();
    if (!options.headers) {
        options.headers = new Headers({
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token
        });
    }
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/poll', body,  options)
        .map((response: Response) => {
            const result = response.json();
            const poll = new Poll(
                result.obj.title,
                result.obj.choice1,
                result.obj.choice2,
                0,
                0,
                result.obj.user.firstName,
                result.obj._id,
                result.obj.user._id,
                );
            this.polls.unshift(poll);
            return poll;
        })
        .catch((error: Response) => {
            this.errorService.handleError(error.json());
            return Observable.throw(error);
        });
}
```

Comment: Sadly, I still get the 400 error :/ and I don't understand the signUp issue, where is lastname missing ?

Comment: when I tried to signUp in your website I got that error. let me check again

Comment: Indeed :/ I need to keep debugging then. I don't know what exactly causes the error.

Comment: let me download your code and check, you are not sending `lastName` to the server while registration. check that

Comment: Ok, the link has been updated with the latest code (I don't think there were many differences anyway)

Comment: Your `bundle.js` does not seem to have latest code, build again as you can see there is no last name in `bundle.js`

Comment: I already built :D I just don't see where to add the last name / modify code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145266/discussion-between-sravan-and-coder1000).

Comment: Ok, I am there !

Comment: I had to debug for some more time, but it worked ! Thank you so much !

Comment: @Coder1000, Glad to help you...anything is left? So that I can help you??

Comment: There is only one thing, I would like to be able to vote again on a poll after editing it. That is: When I edit a poll, and save the edit, the poll votes go back to 0 (as they should) but the poll stays locked: https://voting-app-10.herokuapp.com/polls

Comment: poll stayed locked? didn't get you?

Comment: When you click on the Edit button on one of your own polls and save the edits you make, if you had previously voted on the poll, you can't vote again on the modified poll.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145376/discussion-between-sravan-and-coder1000).

Answer (score 1):

As @trichetriche suggested you should put the token into the header instead of the URL:

```
addPoll(poll: Poll) {
    const body = JSON.stringify(poll);
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    const headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
        });
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/poll', body, {headers: headers})
        .map((response: Response) => {
            const result = response.json();
            const poll = new Poll(
                result.obj.title,
                result.obj.choice1,
                result.obj.choice2,
                0,
                0,
                result.obj.user.firstName,
                result.obj._id,
                result.obj.user._id,
                );
            this.polls.unshift(poll);
            return poll;
        })
        .catch((error: Response) => {
            this.errorService.handleError(error.json());
            return Observable.throw(error);
        });
}
```

Of course you need to change the server code as well and pare the token from the header instead of the query parameter.

As I know 'express-jwt' uses this header parameter by default, but you can parse it manually:

```
function getToken (req) {
    if (req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[0] === 'Bearer') {
        return req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: Here is how I get it from the query parameter: `var decoded = jwt.decode(req.query.token);` How do I get it from the body ?

Comment: You can access header parameters like this: `req.headers['x-token'];` But if it's a jWT token you should use `Authorization` header.

Comment: Could you please update your answer with that info and how to use Authorization header ?

Comment: I get an error 400, you can try creating a poll to see it: https://voting-app-10.herokuapp.com/polls

Answer (score 1):

1. your network request has malformed Authorization token OR it could be you not storing it properly in local storage.
2. pass the poll object instead of body(which is stringifyed, no need to stringify, it need to be valid Json object)

Use RequestOptions..

```
    if (!options.headers)
        options.headers = new Headers();

    options.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json'); //you may not need this though.
    options.headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer '+ token);

    return this.http.post('https://voting-app-10.herokuapp.com/poll', poll, options)

    ....
    ....
```